# How to properly load local AMD modules with jspm/system.js

Tags: javascript, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I am having a really hard time using local AMD modules in an Aurelia project that uses es6, JSPM, and system.js. I am hoping someone out there can help me configure my project to enable me to import/load my AMD modules and use them in my project. The local AMD style modules are in a format similar to the following:

```
define
(['require',
'lib/alerts/STARTSTOP',
'lib/alerts/STOPPED',
...
],
function( require, STARTSTOP, STOPPED, ... ) {
  return {
    alert: function( data ) {
      var type = data.type;
      var ev   = data.event;
      var cls  = require( 'lib/alerts/' + ev );
      return new cls( data );
    }
  };
});
```

When I try to import/load this module into an es6 module I am running into the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous AMD define.`. I get this error when trying to load the module in either of the following ways:

```
System.import('lib/alerts/AlertFactory').then( (m) => {
  console.log( m );
});
```

or

```
import AlertFactory from 'lib/alerts/AlertFactory.js';
```

I have also made sure to add the following script to my index.html:

```
<script>
    window.define = System.amdDefine;
    window.require = window.requirejs = System.amdRequire;
</script>
```

In addition to the above I have also added a meta format property to my config.js file, but that hasn't seemed to help either.

```
meta: {
    ...
    "lib/alerts/*.js": {
      "format": "amd"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why I am running into the error I am seeing and how to properly load my modules? I appreciate any help/insight you can offer.

## UPDATE

I finally realized that the main issue here is that I'm trying to use existing AMD modules in and Aurelia project, and the default Aurelia gulp build assumes that all code is written in ES6 and not mixed with AMD. That's why I'm having issues. Vanilla jspm/system.js handle a mix of module formats, but Aurelia does not out of the box.

Comment: Where is this assumption being made in Aurelia? How can you determine that it is not SystemJS or how Babel is transpiling?

Comment: I'm having a hard time with this too. I'm trying to import this lib (http://savvior.org/) that it's supposed to be an AMD module, but I can't get it working. I got it installed via `jspm install npm:savvior` but I can seem to import it properly in my view-model.

Comment: @Andrew The assumption is being made in the Aurelia skeleton app's gulp configuration files. I'm not sure if things have changed since the version I was using, but in the `build/tasks/build.js` file gulp is converting all files in the `src` folder to AMD modules via Babel. I tested stuff with SystemJS and it supports loading different types of modules side by side. The problem is when you try to transpile a module that's already in the AMD format. That's why the solution was to simply put AMD modules outside of the `src` folder so Gulp/Babel don't try to transpile them.

Comment: @emzero Are you sure you aren't trying to transpile the lib you are trying to use? Make sure it's not in a folder/path that Gulp is running a transpilation task on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put your AMD modules out of `src` so babel will not be able to transpile it. Here is working solution I use to import jquery modules:

First, I have `local_packages` folder in project root and I have jquery module `local_packages/somelib/js/mymodule.js`

Then in `config.js`

```
paths: {
  ...
  "local/*": "local_packages/*",
}

map: {
  ...
  "somelib": "local/somelib",
  "somelib1": "/local_packages/somelib1",
}
```

And finally my import looks like: `import 'somelib/js/mymodule';`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! I thought I was going to have to reconfigure my gulp build task. This is much easier.